# obx does not responsive GetX

Tags: flutter-getx

I am using GetX. I need when the user delete the image from ui, the card delete. But nothing deleted from UI. if i pressed hot restart it deleted from the UI.

**The Code Is:**

```
class SelectedImagesWidget extends GetView<AddProductController> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(
      () => (controller.product.value.pickedImages.isEmpty)
              ? const SizedBox.shrink()
              : SingleChildScrollView(
                  clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    child:ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: controller.product.value.pickedImages
                          .length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Obx(()=>
                           Stack(
                            clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                            children: [
                              // Image
                              Card(
                                clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                                child: // AssetThumb(
                                    Image.file(
                                  controller.product.value.pickedImages
                                      .getOrCrash()[index],
                                ),
                              ),
                              // Delete Button
                              Positioned(
                                child: InkWell(
                                  onTap: () async =>
                                      await controller.deleteImage(index),
                                  child: const CircleAvatar(
                                    child: Icon(
                                      Icons.delete_outlined,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this for refresh list

```
controller.product.refresh()
```

Comment: it does not work :(

Comment: show me this method   --> controller.deleteImage(index),

Comment: i think you should use RXList for this -----> pickedImages

Answer (score 0):

you can use update() function at the end of your logic function in controller

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).